# Can Thonny run scripts as root?

Tags: python, root

I'm trying to use the `Import keyboard` library within Thonny on my Raspberrypi Zero W. However I receive an error saying "*import error: you must be root to use this library on Linux.*"

Can Thonny run scripts as root?

Are there any alternative IDEs that are lightweight that can run scripts as root?

[image: screen_image]

Comment: It is theoretically possible, but extremely inadvisable. You need to ask a proper question and **NOT** post incomplete pictures.

Comment: "Can Thonny run scripts as root?" Did you try running it as root and it didn't work? Or do you want to know how to use `sudo`?